# Slayer exciter not working help

Tags: tesla-coil

I recently made a slayer exciter by using the circuit diagram attached. But my exciter is not working and I have a question.

Is primary coil supposed to be wound the opposite direction as second coil?

The LED in the circuit is just blinking.

I used 12v instead of 9, 450 turns instead of 275 and 6 turns instead of 3.

[image: circuit diagram]

Comment: So you've made a bunch of changes to a circuit you don't understand, and you're surprised when it doesn't work?

Comment: should be opposite direction

Comment: As @Jasen mentioned, reverse your primary connections. Also the high-voltage output must have some current flow or the circuit will not work.

Answer (score 1):

How do you know it's not working? I thought mine wasn't but when I looked at the output with an oscilloscope, there was a 300 volt Peak-to-Peak very clean sine wave. Not enough to draw sparks and light up globes. Now working on a coil that's 100 mm diameter and 300 mm long. I used a 2N3055 transistor on a heat sink and a 12 volt supply.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand that other comment about the high-voltage output requiring some current flow. Mine has nothing connected and produces a faint corona with nothing connected to it.So, it's obviously working.